# SAP Business Objects - Embed in iframe prevent parent redirect

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, business-objects

We are trying to embed SAP BO reports in an intranet site but running into an issue. Using this URL for the iFrame:

> http://server/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?sIDType=CUID&iDocID=[cuid]

The report requires the user to be signed into SAP BO to view, so it's redirecting to the sign in page, but it redirects the parent page, not the iFrame.

I'm aware that I cant hi-jack the redirect and push it back to the iFrame. Surely there must be a setting in BO to disable redirecting the parent when embedded? I read through a bunch of documentation for SAP but can't find anything on this.